# How to build ASP.net MVC application on machine which does not have visual studio?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, msbuild, razor

I have a web hosting space which is on a Windows machine and it does not have visual studio.

I want to work on my ASP.Net MVC 3 website over the internet.

For this once I plan to create a solution in my desktop visual studio and then upload it on the web server and then onwards build  it online. To edit files I will do plain text editor online.

Hence in short,I want to upload the source code on the web server and once I am confident I would like to run some command prompt command which would build my application.

Do I need anything other than **MSBuild** on my web server for this?

Comment: did you try ? what problems did you face ?

Comment: No, I did not try. as my webhosting is on shared web server, I have requested them to install and give me access to MSBuild. 
They have asked me to give list of tools, at once, I will need for my website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the WINSDK(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660764.aspx)  so that you can use MSBuild.

But why do you want this? If you have Vs on your desktop, you can build your solution there and then upload the compiled/published website to the server. Editing files and then compiling with with MSBuild sounds like a pain in the ass.

Comment: Agree that there is nothing like Visual studio, but I will not have access to it all the time. And more over, uploading files on internet is blocked in network where I have desktop with visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use publish property of visual studio. Rightclick in solution explorer then copy publish files to your machine you want to run. In iis, set path coreectly and select .net 4.